# Perform rowspan on c# codebehind- HTML table

Tags: c#, html-table

I have created a table like below using this code. How can I merge/rowspan the empty cells with previous one if the particular cell is empty (here it is second column) ?

```
    HtmlTable table_checklist = ((HtmlTable)tbl_checklist);
    if (dr2.HasRows)
    {   while (dr2.Read())//reading data from database
        {
            HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();
            HtmlTableCell cell1 = new HtmlTableCell();
            HtmlTableCell cell2 = new HtmlTableCell();
            HtmlTableCell cell3 = new HtmlTableCell();
         
            cell1.InnerText = dr2["role_id"].ToString();
            row.Cells.Add(cell1);

            cell2.InnerText = dr2["subject"].ToString();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr2["subject"].ToString()))
            {
              //  cell2.RowSpan = 2;
            }
            row.Cells.Add(cell2);

            cell3.InnerText = dr2["student"].ToString();
            row.Cells.Add(cell3);

            table_checklist.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you create a snippet with the code that is actually generated in the browser and the code that you expect instead? Thanks!

Comment: You'd need to keep a reference to the original cell (the first one with "English" in it) and increment its `Rowspan` property for each successive "English" value. Then you'd need to replace that with a reference to the first one with "Spanish", etc.